# problem with workspaces in xubuntu 11.10 compiz

Tags: compiz, workspaces

I have installed compiz in my xubuntu 11.10 desktop -- x64. I was trying to figure out how the workspaces work in this new set up. Now I have a problem that I need to resolve before I can get back to fix the original problem.

The problem is this: with shift + alt + mouse middle button, a menu came up where it showed an option saying I could add a workspace. I did that. This second workspace is a black diagonal from top left to bottom right. Nothing else works once that comes up. In that menu, there is another option that says to remove the workspace. That doesn't work.

Hope someone can help me remove that.

And then point me to some literature re workspaces in compiz/xubuntu 11.10. I think workspaces became rather complicated after the compiz install.

Answer (score 1):

With Compiz enabled Xfce does not handle workspaces, rather the compizconfig-settings-manager tool does.
Firstly, if you want the middle button in compiz gestures then disable the middle menu click in xfce Settings Manager:

[image: Xfce Settings Manager]

Then you can use CCSM - `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` - to configure the amount of workspaces and how to switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Compiz Settings Manager -> General Options -> Desktop Size to:

Horizontal Virtual Size - 4
Vertical Virtual Size - 1
Number of Desktops - 1

solves the problem of workspace switcher not showing the running applications properly and other issues with the workspaces switcher in Xubuntu 12.10 + Compiz.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, compiz and xfce have a different understanding of workspaces.

Under compiz, I just ignore the workspace settings in xfce and use e.g. docky for workspace switching.

There is no literature that I know of but you might find known issues and workarounds at https://bugzilla.xfce.org/.